# Background on Joshua 5:10-11

Tags: law, moses, joshua, passover

Why were there no celebrations of the Passover while Israel wandered for 40 years in the wilderness?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Please take the tour below.  Thanks for your question.  Is there anything that prompted this question?

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer why there was no Passover during  the wilderness wanders has several components; all practical.

1. Until the Israelites arrived in the promised land they lived on manna and so had no materials with which to celebrate the Passover such as, roasted grain, bitter herbs, etc.  This was symbolised the day after they celebrated the first Passover - manna stopped because they now had access to local produce (Josh 5:11, 12)
2. The people had to be circumcised before partaking of the Passover (Josh 5:5-9)

Thus, the Passover was not celebrated because the elements to celebrate it we not available and because circumcision had not been practised.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing your insight.